# How to extract fields value from Object in Java

Tags: java

Here is `Demo` class

```java
public class Demo {
    int i;
    String s;
}
```

I have an instance of `Demo`:

```java
Demo demo = new Demo(1, "hello");
```

How can I get `demo` field values as array of `Object` like:

```java
Object[] {1, "hello"};
```

### Updated:

For new `Object[] {demo.i, demo.s}` I need know fields from `Demo`, however I need a general way to get `Object` array for any class that has primitive fields and/or simple fields.

Comment: Just build that array yourself, e.g. `new Object[] {demo.i, demo.s}`. However, what are you trying to achieve? Does it even make sense to build such an array in your case?

Comment: Or create a method for that in Demo class, that way it preserves the encapsulation

Comment: @Thomas for `new Object[] {demo.i, demo.s}` I need know fields from Demo, as I need a general way to get Object array for any Class with primitive fields

Comment: You could do that using reflection and there should be libraries for that but the question on the _why_ remains. What are you trying to achieve here? If we know that we might be ale to suggest better solutions. Also, how would you want to handle nested classes? And finally, to be a little nit-picking: `String` is _not_ a primitive :)

Comment: @Thomas reflection should work. and my situation example: I saw a batchUpdate method in  spring-jdbc JdbcTemplate, `public int[] batchUpdate(String sql, List<Object[]> batchArgs)`, I was thinking when should this method be used? If use this method in a general way I need transform `List<Object>` to `List<Object[]>`

Comment: Keep in mind that this method would require the array contents and the SQL parameters to match - in type and order. So having a generic approach would be very hard to get right and instead it makes more sense to build the arrays yourself and according to what the SQL required.

Comment: So this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - in the real use-case you should know what order the fields are needed in, and chances are you have more than just something telling you the order they're in.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to make it yourself indeed. To get it how you showed, you will want a getter method in your object

```
public class Demo(){
  int i;
  String s;
  public Demo(){
    //constructor
  }
  public Object[] getDemo{
    return new Object[] {i, s};
  }
}
```

Comment: this works only when I know fields of Demo class, I need a general way for any Class

Comment: @xring The `Demo` class knows its own fields, so you write it there - and different implementations in each other class you need the method to exist on. Make a common interface for those classes to implement.

Comment: @xring You can't extract unknown fields from outside a class; the class itself must offer a method that returns said fields. This is the only way and by design

Comment: @ThisIsMe actually reflection can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can do it via reflection quite easily:

```
public static Object[] getFieldValues(Object o) {
    return Arrays.stream(o.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .map(field -> {
                try {
                    return field.get(o);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            })
            .toArray();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Demo {
        int i;
        String s;
    }
    Demo d = new Demo();
    d.i = 1;
    d.s = "hello";
    Object[] fieldValues = getFieldValues(d);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fieldValues));
}
```

However, also as stated in the comments, this might be an "X-Y problem" and there may be better solutions to what you are actually looking to achieve.